# How to split by indentifying a pattern and then splitting under a subpatern of that same pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm getting used to the re library and here's the deal:

I have for example this case, this string:

```
x = '501086110 - Werfen Portugal, Lda | 501524177 - Biomérieux Portugal, Lda | 503387398 - ALFAGENE,LDA. | 503842770 - VWR | 504282921 - Roche - Sistemas de Diagnóstico | 507699321 - B|Nice Juices'
```

I want to split it by "|" but only if it has letters or special characters before it, and a number after.

I was doing:

```
re.split(pattern= '\w\s\W\s\d|\W\s\W\s\d', string = x)
```

for this case, it kinda does what I want, but it takes out the last character of split1 and the first character of split2.

Can you suggest a better way to implement this? Ideally I would have as an output:

```
["501086110 - Werfen Portugal, Lda",  "501524177 - Biomérieux Portugal, Lda","503387398 - ALFAGENE,LDA.","503842770 - VWR","504282921 - Roche - Sistemas de Diagnóstico", "507699321 - B|Nice Juices"]
```

Comment: Maybe all you need is `x.split(' | ')`? No need for a regex then if you just need to split with space+`|`+space

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

That was my first try, but then I have cases like this annoying  "507699321 - B|Nice Juices" that would ruin the solution

Comment: But that case is fine. There are no spaces around `|` in `507699321 - B|Nice Juices`

Comment: Yes, but there is another one: "551233478 - AZX | Hospitals"... These names...

Comment: @josemrquintas: Try splitting on `r'(?<=.)\s*\|\s*(?=\d)`

Comment: Then use `re.split(r'(?<=[\w\W])\s+\|\s+(?=\d)', text)`

Comment: @anubhava that was godlike, it worked! can you teach me the logic behind it?

Comment: @josemrquintas: I have posted it below with an explanation. Please let me know if you need more clarity on anything.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew also worked perfectly!! That was amazing, thank you so much! What's the logic? what does it do differently?

Comment: @anubhava 
thank you so much! great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with look-arounds in `split`:

```
(?<=.)\s*\|\s*(?=\d)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OAxwFw/1)

**Code:**

```
>>> import re
>>> x = '501086110 - Werfen Portugal, Lda | 501524177 - Biomérieux Portugal, Lda | 503387398 - ALFAGENE,LDA. | 503842770 - VWR | 504282921 - Roche - Sistemas de Diagnóstico | 507699321 - B|Nice Juices'
>>> reg = re.compile(r'(?<=.)\s*\|\s*(?=\d)')
>>> arr = reg.split(x)
>>> print ( "\n".join(arr) )
501086110 - Werfen Portugal, Lda
501524177 - Biomérieux Portugal, Lda
503387398 - ALFAGENE,LDA.
503842770 - VWR
504282921 - Roche - Sistemas de Diagnóstico
507699321 - B|Nice Juices
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=.)`: Positive lookbehind. Assert that we have any character at previous position
- `\s*\|\s*`: A pipe surrounded by 0 or more whitespaces on either side
- `(?=\d)`: Positive lookahead. Assert that we have a digit at next position